# Show/Hide an image via button or radio button

Tags: image, radio-button

I am new to coding so I am looking for the simplest way to take and image and show or hide it based either on one button or via radio button controls. Currently the image is on as an  but i can use the any recommend method. If at all possible from a different page on my site.

Comment: Have you tried searching for some answers? Try looking at jQuery show and hide

Comment: Most of the answers i find are for some reason beyond me. However I have not tried jQuery show and hide. I will try that now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a button, you could use

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function addimage() { 
              var img = document.createElement("img");
              img.src = "IMAGE_URL_HERE"; 
              img.height = IMAGE_HEIGHT; 
              img.width = IMAGE_WIDTH;

              //optionally set a css class on the image
              var class_name = "foo";
              img.setAttribute("class", class_name);

              document.body.appendChild(img);
            } 
     </script> 
</head> 
<body>
        <button onclick="addimage();">Click</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set this up on a different page then the one where the image will be displayed?